# Cyrillic monospaced fonts problem in beamer

Tags: beamer, pdftex, fontsize, typewriter, cyrillic

**Note: Please scroll down and see the UPD 2, which clarifies the problem.**

I need to use `\texttt` (or even `\verbatim`) in my presentation.
Unfortunately, it looks like it doesn’t work with beamer at all.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[fragile]
        \frametitle{English + русский}
            English is okay.
            Русский работает.
%            \texttt{English} is not okay.
%            \verb+Русский+ не работает.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

If I the uncomment the first commented line with `\texttt{English}`, the document does not compile. The error is

```
Font T2A/cmtt/m/n/10.95=latt1095 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

If I the uncomment the second commented line with `\verb`..., the document does not compile. The error is

```
File ended while scanning use of \next.
```

I am using TexLive on OS X 10.11 with all packages (including `cm-super`) installed and updated. Compiling the same document with `\documentclass{article}` (and deleting `frame` environment with `\frametitle`, of course) works great.

P.S. Please do not try offering XeLaTex, because I have to rely on pdftex.

P.P.S. After playing around for approx. an hour, I found that `\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}` or other variants like `\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}`may help, but it looks more as a hack, than as a solution.

---

**UPD:**

The problem with `verbatim`, `fragile` and spaces is solved, but the main problem remains. The  code from **cfr**’s answer still gives me an error

```
Font T2A/cmtt/m/n/10.95=latt1095 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \verb
```

So my question is about dealing with `\texttt` in beamer.

---

**UPD 2:**

Compiling the following MWE (a bit edited variant of **cfr**’s answer)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american,russian]{babel}
\newcommand*\texteng[1]{\foreignlanguage{american}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{English + русский}
  \texteng{English is okay.} \\
  Русский работает. \\
  \texteng{\texttt{English} is not okay.} \\
  \texttt{Русский} не работает. \\
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Provides this result:

[image: No Cyrillic glyphs for \texttt]

The errors and warnings are these:

```
Font T2A/cmtt/m/n/10.95=latt1095 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \end{frame}
Font shape `T2A/cmss/m/n' in size <4> not available(Font) size <5> substituted
Size substitutions with differences(Font) up to 1.0pt have occurred.
```

The `missfont.log` file contains the following line:

```
mktextfm latt1095
```

And the main `.log` file can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/WUcU9Nv5.

As I mentioned before, all packages are installed, including `cm-super`, and TeXLive utility reports everything is up-to-date.

So there are no Cyrillic glyphs for `\texttt`, and the question is why?

Comment: Welcome! You need to change languages using the commands provided by Babel. You've set the document up to default to Russian. So you need to say when you are using something else. Babel provides both switches and commands for limited bits of text for many languages. If not or if you don't like the names it uses, you can spin your own. For example, `\foreignlanguage{american}{text in US English}`.

Comment: Actually, the error has nothing to do with English. I get the same error if I comment out everything but the line with `\verb`.

Comment: Can you try running from a shell the command `mktextfm latt1095` and tell what happens? Also the output from `tlmgr info lh`, please

Comment: Output for `mktextfm latt1095` can be found here: http://pastebin.com/hhYj8KFE. And here is the output for  `tlmgr info lh`: http://pastebin.com/mWKJE4bk.

Comment: After running these commands the MWE from the UPD 2 compiled successfully! How did it happen? What was the problem with `mktextfm`? By the way, I still have the warnings mentioned in the UPD 2, but the problem is solved! If someone posts an answer explaining this workaround, I’ll have to accept it.

Comment: @egreg Can I ask you for a deeper explanation, please? After some googling I understood the purpose of `mktextfm`, but I still wonder why pdftex didn’t run it by default.

Comment: @EugeneF I have no idea. On my Mac OS X machine it does.

Comment: @egreg Still thanks for help! Maybe you can post your advice about absence of `.tfm` files and the workaround as an answer, so I mark it helpful (accepted)?

Comment: @EugeneF The missing font problem is secondary with respect to the main issue of your question, which was having a space in front of `\end[frame}`. Why `pdflatex` is not able to build the font is really unclear and running manually `mktextfm` is just a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

The problem actually causing the error is simply the space before `\end{frame}` which is not allowed when `fragile` is used.

However, text in English should be marked as such for Babel. Although it can cope with basic Latin script regardless, hyphenation and other niceties will be wrong.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american,russian]{babel}
\newcommand*\texteng[1]{\foreignlanguage{american}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{English + русский}
  \texteng{English is okay.}
  Русский работает.
  \texteng{\texttt{English} is not okay.}
  \verb+Русский+ не работает.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: American English and Russian]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I missed the point with `fragile` and spaces, but the main problem remains. Your code still gives me an error

`Font T2A/cmtt/m/n/10.95=latt1095 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found. \verb`

So now my question is about dealing with `\texttt` in beamer.

Comment: In that case, you are missing the relevant fonts and need to install them. I am guessing you are using MikTeX or the packages provided by a Linux distro in that case because a default TeX Live installation would provide them out-of-the-box. You need to install `cm-super`, I think. At least, that's what gets used when I compile this. You could alternatively tweak the `\texteng` macro to switch fonts and encoding (to `T1` etc. explicitly) but installing the fonts will be the better option. (Or use fonts you know you have installed and use in other documents with the `professional` Beamer theme.)

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post, I am using TexLive on OS X 10.11 with all packages (including `cm-super`) installed and updated. Therefore, my question was how this can possible.

Comment: @EugeneF Then probably you should post the log file. But make sure that MacTeX is fully updated first.

Comment: Please see the second update of the question: I added the info from missfont.log and the link to the main `.log` file.